# UIView subclass itself gets pixelated in retina

Tags: ipad, uiview, retina-display

I have an UIView subclass which is loaded in a UIViewController when needed. This view works fine in iPhone 3/4/5 or seems working fine. It also looks okay in iPad 1/2. But for iPad retina screen, the view is pixelated. All the labels, button, view background, texts are pixelated.

Earlier I did not override the drawRect method. But with some other SO hints I did that. But still did not solve the problem.

Any idea, where's the problem with retina display?

Comment: Do you see this also with built in fonts?

Comment: yes, the fonts, button labels, text placeholder in uitextfield all... seems the whole view is stretched as an image!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Ok, I figure out the problem.

The view uses a kinds nested view, and one of the view layer was manipulated and called the

```
layer.shouldRasterize = YES;
```

But if I add this line, that fixes the problem.

```
layer.rasterizationScale = [UIScreen mainScreen].scale;
```

In the apple WWDC 2012 they have a video on this. "Polishing Your Interface Rotations". Here they discussed the issue. 
https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2012/

Comment: Good find! I had the same problem on many views throughout my app, and was going through printing view frames to the log expecting to find fractional origins or something. This saved me from a lot of grey hairs, thanks.